# Getting Day name from day of week

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 7 Records in my mysql Database
each corresponsing to day of week from 0-6

Now i my PHP script I want to display instead of 0, 'Sunday' or instead of 1 would like to show 'Monday'.

Is there any function available that takes a numeric days of week and returns Name of week day?

Comment: `if row equals zero, echo Sunday`

Comment: Then I have to add 7 ifs is it a better way to write the code?

Comment: Basically, yes. `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query){ if($row['date'] == 0) { echo "Sunday"; } ... }` type of thing. I'm sure there are other ways, using `case/switch` for example is one.

Comment: Or use `switch` to shorten the code a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the date function, with the format `l`:

> l (lowercase 'L')
>
> A full textual representation of the day of the week

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

and use the fact that Sunday is 0:

```
echo date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$day_number} days"));
```

Or as a function:

```
function getDayNameFromDayNumber($day_number) {
    return date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$day_number} days"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array with the days in it. Then you can call the day by the index.

0 - 6 = Sunday - Saturday

```
$daynum = 0; // assuming that's what was returned from the database.
$dow = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
echo $dow[$daynum]; // would echo Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls for an enum. PHP doesn't support enums in general, but has a SPL library for enums, it is unsafe to be used as the server may not have it installed.

another way is to use a numeric array for days of week:

```
$daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",];
```

Now calling `$daysOfWeek[$x%7];` returns the string for that day (%7 is to evade out of range indexes).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use arrays. And you should use numbers from 0-6 - it was good idea.

```
$number_of_day = 6; //OR DIFFERNT - it depends what you need
$day_array = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
$day_array[$number_of_day];
```

In variable $day_array[$number_of_day]; you have hour output.

Answer (score 0):

To get **Sunday to Saturday** or **Sun to Sat** from numeric days of the week **0 to 6**:

```
//For example, our target numeric day is 0 (Sunday):
$numericDay = 0; //assuming current date('w')==0 and date('D')=='Sun';
```

***Solution-1:*** Using PHP's built-in function  [jddayofweek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) which starts from `Monday` whereas `date('w')` starts from `Sunday`:

```
jddayofweek($numericDay-1, 1); //returns 'Sun', here decreasing by '-1' is important(!)
//jddayofweek(0, 1); //returns 'Mon';
//jddayofweek(0, 2); //returns 'Monday';
```

***Solution-2:*** Using a trick:

```
date('D', strtotime("Sunday +{$numericDay} days")); //returns 'Sun';
//date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$numericDay} days")); //returns 'Sunday';
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write a helper and pass the date into it. It'll be available in all of your views anywhere you need it: `echo $this->MyHelper->changeNumToDate($num)`
Since you're using return you don't need break really, but its habit with me.

```
class MyHelper extends Helper {
    function changeNumToDate($num = null){
        Switch($num){
            Case 0:
                return 'Sunday';
                break;
            Case 1:
                return 'Monday';
                break;
            Case 2:
                return 'Tuesday';
                break;
            Case 3:
                return 'Wednesday';
                break;
            Case 4:
                return 'Thursday';
                break;
            Case 5:
                return 'Friday';
                break;
            default:
                return 'Saturday';

        }
    }
}
```